# Reflecting pixels on a line

Tags: java, image, rgb

The aim is to 'move' (some of) the pixels in a square sub-area (square(x,y)), of an image.

I do this by going through each horizontal line in that square and working out which will be moved. So moving them in an inverse way.

Given I have a horizontal line of pixels in my square (x,y)

A..............B.........C

After applying a transformation, the pixels after B till C will turn black. The pixel at C 'moves' to A, and the pixels in between B and P are moved and scaled linearly from A to B.

This means that A to B pixels are a stretched reflection of B to C. But the pixel at B stays the same.

My problem is working out the positions of A and C, which would be the right hand side and left hand side of the square (x,y).

So far, I have this:  size is half of length or width of square

```
// check if square(x,y) lies within image
if ( (x<image.getWidth()) && (y<image.getHeight()) ){   
   if (( y<=0) && (y >= image.getHeight())){ //not sure whether these if's are right
      for (int i=0; i<x-size; i++) {// visiting each pixel in square(x,y) at coordinate (i,j) 
         for(int j=0; j< y-size; j++){ 
           // set values for A(left hand side), C(right hand side), B(x +n)
            int A= 
            int B= 
            int B= x+n;
```

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, just fyi. I'm not even quite sure I understand what you are exactly trying to do

Comment: If A and C are the endpoints, wouldn't one just be at `0` and the other at `image.getWidth() - 1`? Or am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @rabbitguy reflect pixels in a horizontal line

Comment: @911DidBush not necessarily, since I can move my cursor anywhere on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you have a small square area inside a bigger image, but you're running a "for loop" through the entire image instead of the square (which I assume is moving across the screen from some keyboard commands or mouse movement).

In the case of mouse movement, your mouse would be centered in the square, at a position (x,y). In each horizontal line of pixels in the square, your A would be (x - (square.width/2)), your B would be (x + n), and your C would be (x + (square.width/2).

Comment: yes but I should be looping my for loop through each xy in the square at I,j

Comment: if your square is like 100 by 100, and your reflection mirror is in the center, then you would be looping through each horizontal line, and "moving" the pixels from C-B to A-B, you'd probably need an equation if B (the reflection line) can move left or right.

Comment: I guess that's the linear equation I'm trying to work out

Comment: I assume you're also in CO2016 ;)

Comment: try solving for m and k in the prei = mi + k equation, thats the only hint i'll give ya lol